# Need help with current sensing parameter

Tags: datasheet

[image]

In the above, I understood the term current sensing. Just to confirm as to what the percentages mean, are they the error or range of estimation for the sensed current at load?

[Ref](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps281c30.pdf?ts=1681918217913&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS281C30%253FkeyMatch%253DTPS281C30%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)

Comment: What do you mean by "range of estimation"? How is that different from error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet says that you have an error of ±4% at 1A load current.

The device measures the current flowing into the load and generates a current I<sub>SNS</sub> on the I<sub>SNS</sub> pin, which is proportional to the load current (gain : 1/K<sub>SNS</sub>). K<sub>SNS</sub> is declared at 1300A/A on the electrical parameters. So for 1A load current you have approximately I<sub>SNS</sub> = 0.764mA (±4%).

If you then connect a resistor from I<sub>SNS</sub> pin to ground, a voltage will appear across this resistor. You can then sense this voltage using an OPA or directly by connecting an ADC + some passive filtering.

If you do so, please note that you will also have to account for the resistor precision (+ OPA offsets).

Comment: For high accuracy mode, I’d follow the same steps but change the ‘K’ value as mentioned in the data sheet, then on that value there can be a potential error of +-12.5% right?

Comment: Did the maths and it worked out, thanks!

Comment: For example 40mA/Ksns2 = 1.62mA (Ksns2 = 24.6 in high accuracy mode). You would get +/-6% accuracy on that value. Don't take this +/-12.5% value everytime. Refer to the table in 7.6!

Answer (score 0):

This is the *current measurement accuracy*, so I believe the answer you're looking for is the error. As per the Electrical Characteristics description of value Isns on Page 9 of the datasheet, these values are the +- tolerances for different input current levels. In plain words, when you give this chip an input current of 1A, it will measure a value somewhere between 0.96A and 1.04A because 4% of 1A is 40mA.

What I can't figure out is why the percentages and the mA values are different - we know 4% of 1A is 40mA, but the datasheet explicitly states 0.764mA as well. My best guess is that is the mA value is the minimum error you would see at that current level, with the percentages being the lower/upper bounds.

Comment: The datasheet says Isns comes from a current mirror and is the reflect of the 1A current flowing into the load divided by a gain Ksns, which will give 0.764mA for 1A load as Ksns = 1300A/A. And you have +/-4% accuracy on this 0.764mA mirrored current.

Answer (score 0):

If not noted otherwise, sensing accuracy is - in my experience - given for FSR.

**(1)** So for `FSR=1A` with a tolerance of `+/-4%`, your measurement can deviate from the actual current by `up to 40mA.`

**(2)** If noted in the datasheet, there can also be a static error and a range specific error. E.g.: `+-10mA +5%`. This means, your measruement is always off by at least 10mA and 5% of the actual current flowing - `so no longer depended on the FSR.`

**NOTE:** When digitizing the signal, or working with a digitized intermediate, there are other factors at play as well!